# C# 7:How can I deconstruct an object into a single value using a tuple?

Tags: c#, tuples, c#-7.0

One of the nice new features of C# 7 is the possibility to define deconstructors for classes and assign the deconstructed values directly to a value tuple.

However, in the case that the object is deconstructed into a single value, I can't find a way to assign it to a tuple. Although there is a type for tuples with a single element (`ValueTuple<T>`), the shorthand syntax using parentheses doesn't work here. The only way I found to access the deconstructor was to call the `Deconstruct` method directly, but this eliminates its benefit, as I could use any method for this end.

Does anyone know a better way to deconstruct an object into a single value?

Here is my test code:

```
class TestClass
{
    private string s;
    private int n;
    public TestClass(string s, int n) => (this.s, this.n) = (s, n);
    public void Deconstruct(out string s) => s = this.s;
    public void Deconstruct(out string s, out int n) => (s, n) = (this.s, this.n);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var testObject = new TestClass("abc", 3);

    var (s1) = testObject; // sytax error (comma expected)
    ValueTuple<string> t = testObject; // error: "no implicit conversion from TestClass to (string)"
    testObject.Deconstruct(out string s2); // this works
    var (s3, n) = testObject; // no problem

    Console.WriteLine($"{s1} {t.Item1} {s2} {s3} {n}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: not too familiar with ValueTuples, but maybe the line making the ValueTuple should look like: ValueTuple<string> t = ValueTuple.Create(testObject);

Comment: Here I also get the error that there's no implicit conversion form TestClass to ValueTuple<string>.

Comment: Do you actually need to deconstruct it to tuple? Maybe you're looking for implicit cast? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit

Comment: @Oleh - You are right, I could define an implicit conversion operator to string. But I could have done that before C# 7 - so there's still no benefit in the deconstructor with one parameter.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Although there is a type for tuples with a single element (`ValueTuple<T>`), the shorthand syntax using parentheses doesn't work here.

That's correct. The tuple syntax only works for tuples of 2 values or more, so the `Deconstruct` method with only one `out` parameter is not very useful. (There is even a `ValueTuple` type for 0 elements)

The shortest solution is to just ignore the 2nd parameter:

```
var (s1, _) = testObject;
```

Edit: based on comments, a little clarification.
As of C# 7, `_` is no longer a variable in this situation. It is a new feature called 'discard'.
Even if you have multiple out parameters (and even if they are different types) you can ignore any of them with an underscore:

```
var (s1, _, _, _) = testObject;
```

Comment: To be clear, there's nothing special about underscore (`_`) here. Underscore is a valid part of a variable name--including the first character. So you're simply ignoring by convention, not by any magic of underscore.

Comment: Thank you, this works - if only because TestClass also has an additional deconstructor with two parameters.

Comment: @KennethK. No, it is not a variable. It is actually a new feature of C# 7. You can use an underscore to ignore out values. Even if you have multiple of different types, you can say `var (s1, _, _, _) = testObject`

Comment: @Kenneth Thank you for this clarification. I actually though the underscore has Haskell-like sematics here.

Comment: @HelmutD It does. It is NOT a variable.

Comment: @Dennis - Ok. Another nice feature of c# 7 I didn't know of. Are tuples the only context, where underscores can be used?

Comment: @HelmutD It works for any `out` variable. for example those `TryParse` methods. But I think you have to say `out _` then. (Still not a variable)

Comment: I see underscores can also be used in type patterns. Very handy if I only need the type check and not the object.

Comment: @Dennis_E I am corrected. I assume my assertion still holds true for lambdas, or did they change that too?

Comment: @KennethK. No, nothing has changed there. `_` is still a valid variable name. Only in these new cases does it work as an ignore. (They want to be backwards compatible after all) In fact, if you declare a `_` variable, the output value will be assigned to it. That is a little weird and I wish they had used `*` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Deconstructions into a single element are not supported in C# 7.0.

It is unclear why you would need such a mechanism, as you can simply access a property or write a conversion operator to achieve the same thing.

Conceptually, a tuple of one element is just that one element (you don't need a tuple to hold it). So there is no tuple syntax (using parentheses notation) to facilitate that (not to mention it would be syntactically ambiguous). The same applies for deconstructions.

Here are the most relevant LDM notes I could find: [2017-03-15](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/meetings/2017/LDM-2017-03-15.md#zero-and-one-element-tuples) (zero and one element tuples and deconstructions).

It is possible that such deconstruction could become allowed in some future recursive pattern scenarios, but that has not been finalized yet.

Comment: It'll be handy if you use `ITuple` as a generic type constraint - i.e. `(long NamedParam)` vs `(long NamedParam, int _)`

Comment: "why you would need such a mechanism"... because maybe I have similar contexts that I'd like to treat with the same code patterns. Maybe in 2-3 cases, I have 2, 3, 4 variables, in one case I have just 1 variable. Why do I have to use another code construct just for that single case, making the code less coherent?