# How to use ValueTuple with a single item?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5, c#-7.0, valuetuple

In an ASP.NET Core 5 MVC application, I have this call:

```
var result = ctx.ExecQuery<(string Item1)>("select '' as Item1");
```

This throws 5 compile-time errors starting at

> Invalid expression term 'string'

The following works:

```
var result = ctx.ExecQuery<(string Item1, bool _)>("select '' as Item1");
```

How to create a ValueTuple containing a single member so that using `bool _` can avoided?

Comment: `ExecQuery<string>` throws `type string does not have a default constructor`. Is it reasonable to modify `ExecQuery` to support value types ?

Comment: isn't the whole _point_ of a tuple is to pack _multiple_ items?

Comment: In case in question, point of tuple is to create class with `one` item. ExecQuery creates class and assigns values to its properties. There is `ValueTuple<T>` class which has one item and can used to fix the issue . Do you think that `ValueTuple<T>` is pointless C# defect ?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1595

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# 7:How can I deconstruct an object into a single value using a tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975958/c-sharp-7how-can-i-deconstruct-an-object-into-a-single-value-using-a-tuple)

Comment: If you don't need it to be named, then maybe you can use `.ExecQuery<ValueTuple<string>>`?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44975958/c-sharp-7how-can-i-deconstruct-an-object-into-a-single-value-using-a-tuple#comment104179944_44989440